# How to return value from Autoit to java program?

Tags: autoit

I have tired giving return statement in my autoit script.
But it is return the Process name.
I am not able return values from Autoit script to java program.

Comment: You should edit your question and add the Java code that calls your AutoIt script.

Answer (score 0):

With AutoItX you can create a .dll from your AutoIt code, then you can call your function.

> Also supplied is a combined COM and DLL version of AutoIt called AutoItX that allows you to add the unique features of AutoIt to your own favourite scripting or programming languages!
>   [Source](https://www.autoitscript.com/site/autoit/)